# stuck scraping the same 2nd page with infinite scroll

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to scrape game reviews from steam.
when running the spider above, I get the first page with 10 reviews.
then the second page with 10 reviews three times

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MySpider"
    download_delay = 6
    page_number = 1
    start_urls = (
    'https://steamcommunity.com/app/1794680/reviews/', 
    )

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'LOG_ENABLED': False,
        'LOG_FILE': 'logging.txt',
        'LOG_FILE_APPEND': False,
        'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
        'FEEDS': {"items.json": {"format": "json", 'overwrite': True},},
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        for review in soup.find_all('div', class_="apphub_UserReviewCardContent"):
           {...}
            
        if(self.page_number<4):
            self.page_number +=1
            yield scrapy.Request('https://steamcommunity.com/app/1794680/homecontent/?userreviewscursor=AoIIPwYYanu12fcD&userreviewsoffset={offset}&p={p}&workshopitemspage={p}&readytouseitemspage={p}&mtxitemspage={p}&itemspage={p}&screenshotspage={p}&videospage={p}&artpage={p}&allguidepage={p}&webguidepage={p}&integratedguidepage={p}&discussionspage={p}&numperpage=10&browsefilter=trendweek&browsefilter=trendweek&l=english&appHubSubSection=10&filterLanguage=default&searchText=&maxInappropriateScore=100'.format(offset=10*(self.page_number-1) ,p=self.page_number),method='GET', callback=self.parse)
```

[json output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h1U1.png)

I took a few request when scrolling the reviews.
I changed all values that looked like page number and replaced them with {p},
also I tried changing the 'userreviewsoffset' to fit the request format

i noticed that 'userreviewscursor' has a changing value every request but I don't know where it is from.

Comment: Have you checked https://youtu.be/EelmnSzykyI ?
I usually use selenium to easily do load-more functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `userreviewscursor=AoIIPwYYanu12fcD` part of the url. That bit will change for every call, and you can find it in the HTML response under:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userreviewscursor" value="AoIIPwYYanLi8vYD">
```

Get that `value` and add it to the next call, and you're alright. (didn't want to babysit you and write the full code, but if needs be, let me know).